# How can I change the display name in Active Directory with powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How can I change the Name attribute in Active Directory in powershell?

[image]

I would like to change the 'Name' row, but when I enter the following I get an error:

```
Set-ADuser -Identity test1 -Name Test 11
```

The error message:

```
Set-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Name'.
At line:1 char:28
+ Set-ADUser -Identity test1 -Name Test 11
+                            ~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the cmdlet [Rename-ADObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/rename-adobject?view=win10-ps) to change the name attribute of the AD object.

Comment: What Olaf said here but also consider using the `-Whatif` parameter, it'll essentially tell you what your command would have done if you hadn't have added the `-whatif` (it's a good way to keep your job instead of renaming the whole companies display name to the same thing!).

Comment: Ok, please tell me it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change multiple properties for an account in one go (say changing a users name), add the `PassThru` param to `Set-AdUser` and then pipe to `Rename-ADObject`:

```
Set-ADUser -Identity "test1" -DisplayName "DisplayName" -GivenName "GivenName" -Surname "Surname" -PassThru | Rename-ADObject -NewName "TestAccount1" -PassThru
```